# Hiding the truth or statement of your faith?

Tags: genesis, abraham

In Genesis 22:5

> Then Abraham said to his young men, “Stay here with the donkey, and I
> and the boy will go over there; and we will worship and return to
> you.”

Was Abraham hiding the truth or is it an expression of his faith?

Comment: I'm a fan of most of your contributions Tiago, but you ought to be more careful with creating and answering your own questions - this one has a very popular duplicate, which I suspect wasn't scrutinised at the time because it had already been answered

Comment: @SteveTaylor I do look for them but not always possible to find a potential duplicate. In fact, I've been awarding bounties in some which I'd ask and that don't have clear relevant answe, or simply adding them to bookmarks.

Comment: Fair enough, happens to all of us! You do provide an immense number of positive contributions to the site, so thanks again for all that you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to that can be found in Hebrews 11:17-19

> 17 By faith Abraham, when he was tested, offered up Isaac, and the one
> who had received the promises was offering up his only son; 18 it was
> he to whom it was said, “Through Isaac your descendants shall be
> named.” 19 He considered that God is able to raise people even from
> the dead, from which he also received him back as a type.

In other words, it was a statement of faith. Abraham believed God was able to raise Isaac from the dead and so he had faith both him and Isaac would be back.